# Git - support for exotic charset

Tags: git, character-encoding, abas

I'm working in the environment of abas-ERP, which uses - for historical reasons - an esoteric charset named abas-s3. We use Git with local repositories on the ERP-server for versioning our programs.

Naturally Git doesn't support abas-s3. On the erp-servers there is a program called s3_conv, which converts from abas-s3 to the outside world (e.g. UTF-8 and UTF-16) and the other way round.

Is there any way to use this program, to use UTF-8 for the repository and s3 for the worktree?

I appreciate any feedback! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the problem is with *file contents*, you can use **clean/smudge filters** (see [gitattributes](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html)) to have Git convert to UTF-8 when storing to repository, and to abas-s3 when checking out the contents into the working area.

You can find explanation also in [Pro Git](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes) book.

---

Summary:

1. You need to define **in the config file** (per repository, per user, or system-wide) a **filter** consisting of two commands: `clean` that transforms from working area representation to repository representation, and `smudge` that works in reverse.  Assuming that `s3_conv` works like `iconv`, it could look like this (this is a fragment of appropriate config file):

   ```
   [filter "s3conv"]
       clean  = s3_conv --from abas-s3 --to utf-8
       smudge = s3_conv --from utf-8 --to abas-s3
   ```
2. Declare with **gitattributes file** (inside repository, or per-repository, or per-user, or system-wide) which files should be transformed using this operation.  Assuming that you want to transform files with SQL, using `*.sql` extension, appropriate fragment of a file could look like this (note that there cannot be whitespace around `=` here):

   ```
   *.sql filter=s3conv
   ```

Note that Git is encoding-agnostic, and you don't need to convert the contents of files... unless you need it for interop?

---

If you need to have `git diff` display changes correctly (assuming that you don't have pager that can display abas-s3 encoding, and could be used in `core.pager`), you might want to configure **`textconv` filter** ***INSTEAD***:

1. In config file:

   ```
   [diff "s3conv"]
        textconv = s3_conv --from abas-s3 --to utf-8
   ```

   This assumes that terminal and pager is configured to display utf-8
2. In gitattributes file:

   ```
   *.sql diff=s3conv
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and sorry for my late response. I will try this out on monday, and let you know the result!